# Does bitcoin mining need a lot of internet bandwidth

Tags: mining-pools, bandwidth, guiminer

I'm going to be a bitcoin miner and my question is

does it require a lot of internet bandwidth to mine with a pool ??

I'm gonna use guiminer with slush's pool

I have 1MB dsl is it enough ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bitcoin mining doesn't require much bandwidth at all!

It's worth noting that the higher the hash-rate of your rig, the more bandwidth it will require (as you will get through work units faster - downloading new ones and feeding back more frequently).

Seeing as though you are planning to use guiminer, you most likely won't use much bandwidth (most high-performance mining is now done with dedicated equipment as opposed to GPU/CPU mining).

If you're new to mining bitcoins, these sites might be of interest to you:

- https://www.bitcoinmining.com/
- https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining